# xampp virtual host - always loading htdocs

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, vhosts

I am trying to create a virtual host on my localhost (XAMPP). Tried every combination out there, but I always get htdocs loaded instead of the specific folder

Here is the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 devsnappy
```

Here is `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot E:/xampp/htdocs/snappy/public
    ServerName devsnappy
    <Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs/snappy/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you correctly restart httpd ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/examples.html) to add vhost to xampp

Seems that you miss something with the hosts file.

> For example, say you had another Web site for ClientB. You’d add 127.0.0.1    clientB.local >in the hosts file and the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf would look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientA\website"
    ServerName clientA.local
  <Directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientA\website">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientB\website"
    ServerName clientB.local
  <Directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientB\website">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And **restart** httpd

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the `hosts` file. A better guess would be that he simply forgot to restart the apache server after modifying `httdp-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: i copy pasted the example from the guide ... changed the paths ... restarted and worked ... then changed back to my custom vhost name ... restarted and worked ... i do not exactly what the pb was (this guide was the first one i did) but if someone has the same pb as me it might help to follow this answer ... thanks all

Comment: +1 - Sorry, my mistake I though you were talking about the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Worked for me too. +1 for the fix :)

Comment: I am sorry but that guide link is broken, can you please update ?

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who reads this and no solution help you, this is what helped me.

Just uncomment this Include line in your httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

That way, it will make changes you made in your etc/extra/**httpd-vhosts.conf** available!

Don't forget to restart Apache server afterwards!

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks <3 <3 :* :*

Comment: oh man, just wasted 1 hour of my precious life fiddling with httpd-vhosts.conf file to finally find it was commented in httpd.conf, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Saved my day :) I was missing this and debugging from 2 hours

Answer (score 2):

Oh, It was really for painful for me to get it work in Apache 2.4.9.I found a lot of tutorials, but I can not make it work.

MY SOLUTION IS FOR  APACHE 2.4 AND ABOVE VERSION.I have tested it with Apache 2.4.9

You need to edit two files.PLEASE MAKE BACKUP OF THIS TWO FILE BEFORE YOU MAKE CHANGES.If you write anything wrong , your localhost will not work even you uninstall xampp and then again install xampp.

**STEP 1:**

Edit this file

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Open this file using "Run As Adminstrator" from Notepad(Very Important).You can do this by

Start Menu > Notepad >Right Click > Run As Adminstrator > Open file

add these two lines at the end of this file

```
127.0.0.1       testsite.dev
127.0.0.1       www.testsite.dev
```

Either you go testsite.dev or www.testsite.dev , it will now try to access from your local machine NOT from the web

**STEP 2:**

E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

You can edit this file normally , there is no need to run this file as "Run As Adminstrator"
Add the follwing lines at the end of this file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@.testsite.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/htc"
    ServerName testsite.dev
    ServerAlias www.testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I setmy xampp in E drive , so when you copy from here , make sure you change it according to your xampp installation.the Last part is little interesting.I am pointing out this potion

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@.testsite.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/htc"
    ServerName testsite.dev
    ServerAlias www.testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Where can you find this code?In internet , you can find it in many places but might not work for you as that code will differentiate from your Apache version.SO WHAT"S THE SOLUTION?

At the end of file , you will see there are some commented lines already to show you a demo how to setup virtual host, just copy those lines and make necessary changes and it will work for you.I have attached a screenshot for better understanding

http://postimg.org/image/5pug9f42p/

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use .DEV, the registry is now owned by Google and it forces your Chrome to SSL (443). Try .app, or .lan.
2. Make sure that your browser is not loading the HTTPS (port 443) while Apache gets connections only on 80 port, like <VirtualHost *:80>.